# Where does ".type" come from in ts-node?

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I found this code on https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node:

const x = 10;
.type x

What is does is clear but i found nothing about it in official typescript documentation...

Comment: It's not part of TypeScript, only `ts-node`.

Answer (score 1):

That command is [an extension registered in `ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/blob/750eccae4a594b429639d24ce6215afdd3a100aa/src/bin.ts#L264-L280). In fact, it's the only such extension currently in `ts-node`.

The format (and [additional commands such as `.exit`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_commands_and_special_keys)) comes from Node's [built-in `repl` package](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), which `ts-node` consumes and extends.